# Python pymssql Select Sequence Number Returning Strange Value

Tags: sql, python-3.x, byte, pymssql

I'm busy querying a SQL Server DB with Python's pymssql and am getting a strange result from the following query

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select current_value from sys.sequences where name = 'testSequence'")
currentValue = cursor.fetchone()[0]
cursor.close()
print(currentValue)
```

The value in the print is showing as `b'.\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Then when I try to convert the bytes into an integer

```
currentValue = int.from_bytes(cursor.fetchone()[0], byteorder="big")
```

I get an outrageously big number `3530822107858468864`

Executing the exact same query in the SQL Server Studio I can see that the actual `current_value` is only `40`. Am I doing a conversion wrong or is there something I'm not seeing?

*NOTE*

Just adding an extra mention that I'm using Python3 (in case anyone doesn't see the tag)

Comment: which datatype has current_value

Comment: It's datatype is `long`

Comment: No it isn't, I'm mistaken it's `bigint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bigint is converted to float64, you can use CAST and VARCHAR and circumvent it

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select CAST(current_value AS VARCHAR(20)) AS current_value from sys.sequences where name = 'testSequence'")
currentValue = cursor.fetchone()[0]
cursor.close()
print(currentValue)
```

Comment: Just curious but why did you cast it as a varchar 20? Does it need to be specifically 20 characters long?

Comment: max number of bigint is 9223372036854775807 + sign